# Riemann-Stieltjes Integral - Changing Order of Integration

Tags: riemann-integration

I am new to Riemann-Stieltjes integral. I want to ask a very basic question regarding changing the order of integration.

Let $ t > 0 $ and I have an integral that looks like this
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^t f(g(x)) dx dg(x). $$

What is the condition so that I change the order of integration? Or mathematically we could write the integral like this
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} \int_0^t f(g(x)) dx dg(x) = \int_0^t \int_\mathbb{R} f(g(x))dg(x)dx $$

Comment: I believe we still need the same assumptions Fubini requires. Is $f$ a functoom of a single variable?

Comment: Function $ f $ is a function of $ g(x) $ and $ x $. For example, the simplest one is $ f(x) = g(x) + x $.